# Create a report to show account details on different date range

Tags: reporting, account, custom-reports

I want to create a single report to show account details on different date range.

For example:

- accounts created in last 7 days
- accounts created in last 8-14 days
- accounts created in last 15-30 days

I have attached a screenshot to better understand my requirement. Please check: [image]

Please let me know if this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to create a summary report based on date. But it shows result based a particular date! And I want result to be shown based on a certain date range. Please assist..

Comment: There is an workaround for your requirement. Create a pick-list field having options like 7 days old, 8-14 days old etc According to your requirement.  Now create a workflow/Process builder and update the records like if created ate is less then 7 days  update the picklist field with '7 days' option and similarly for others. Now create a report of Summary type and use that picklist field to summaries your result.

Comment: check my answer and nice way to explore bucket fields and summary reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach to meet this requirement.

- Create a formula field like `Day Diff` as Number which will calculate number of days from Createddate.

  `FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate))`
- Go to Report and define Bucket field as follows. Here I have tried to define based on the data at my DE.

[image: Bucket field]

- Now change the report type as Summary Report and place that bucket field for grouping and finally run the report. It will look like this.

[image: Summary Report]

Comment: Wow! That's awesome..! I was not aware of Bucket field. Thanks a lot..!

Comment: I have post this use case in my blog yesterday